# NSPredicate for 2 to-many relationships

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I'm having a problem with the syntax of a NSPredicate. I have 3 entities: A, B and C. A has a many-to-many relationship to B. B has a many-to-many relationship to C. I want to fetch all managed objects in A that have at least one relationship with an object in B which, in turn, has a relationship with at least one object in C.

I have tried a few variations of SUBQUERY and ANY but I'm obviously not using the right syntax.

I have tried:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *ent = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"A" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
fetchRequest.entity = ent;
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SUBQUERY(B, $b, $b.c.@count > 0).@count > 0)"];
```

That resulted in:

**2014-06-30 09:07:12.143 My App[86086:60b] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Keypath containing KVC aggregate where there shouldn't be one; failed to handle $b.jobs.@count'**

Then:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY b.c.@count > 0"];
```

resulted in:

**2014-06-30 09:10:14.403 My App[86186:60b] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported function expression count:(b.c)'**

Also:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SUBQUERY(B, $b, $b.c.@count > 0))"];
```

resulted in:

**2014-06-30 09:17:25.883 My App[86218:60b] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "(SUBQUERY(B, $b, $b.c.@count > 0))"'**

Finally:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SUBQUERY(B, $b, $b.c).@count > 0)"];
```

ended with:

**2014-06-30 09:18:30.202 My App[86272:60b] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "(SUBQUERY(B, $b, $b.c).@count > 0)"'**

Anyone has any idea? There must be an easy way to do this fetch...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(bs, $b, ANY $b.cs != NULL).@count > 0"]
```

where "bs" is the to-many relationship from entity **A** to **B**, and "cs" is the to-many relationship from **B** to **C**.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! How did you come up with that query? I'm still struggling to figure out the SQL query in my head and then translating it to an NSPredicate. I should mention that I'm not a database administrator or guru...

Comment: @nemesys: I had that figured out some time ago with try-and-error :) Generally, I would not try to think in terms of SQL, but in terms of (Core Data) relationships.

Comment: @MartinR Hi Martin, great answer, may be you can help me please. My relationship Object<->>addresses<->>phones i need to check if phones.tel contains my phone number, I try [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY addresses.phones.tel = %@", telNumber] but i get error ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'multiple to-many keys not allowed here', can you advise something? Thank you!